# set databaseName property for XPages app on Bluemix

Tags: xpages, ibm-cloud, xpages-ssjs

I am testing the XPages runtime on Bluemix but have some questions regarding defining the datasources.

So I took the teamroom application as example. In custom control addMember.xsp as Data Source is set a Domino Document. For the application is have selected 'Other' and computed the value as followed:

```
bluemixContext.getDataService().findDataBaseName()
```

Unfortunately when I test this code (members.xsp, Add Member button) after submitting no document is created in the database.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: databaseName="#{javascript:bluemixContext.getDatabaseService().findDatabaseName()}"

Comment: Are you testing this on Bluemix or w/ local web preview?

Comment: i am testing on bluemix. I noticed there is a mixup with the form aliases so I  can close this answer

Comment: Ah, that'll do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a mixture in the form aliases